# Using telephone links on mobile devices

Tags: iphone, html, hyperlink, skype, tel

Ok, I know its possible to get a number to be callable with Skype using `callto:`, and I know its possible to get a number clickable on iOS and droids by using `tel:` in an a tag.

However, what about tablets/iPads? Does this work for them?

What if they have Skype installed on their iPad and click a `tel:` link.

I believe you cant make calls from an iPad or droid tablet even with a service plan (I dont own either, just an assumption. Enlightenment would be great). Would `callto:` work for a mobile browser to make them use Skype instead (if installed, obviously)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it would not work. The way Skype accomplishes this on a desktop is through an extension installed in the browser. On an iPad you cannot install these types of browser extensions. It may be possible on an Android tablet.

Edit:

My answer is based on the assumption that you would visit a page with telephone links and you are asking if the browser will perform like it does on a desktop. Where the browser will 'rewrite' tel: tags you use Skype if installed.

Edit 2:

Updated answer to reflect @[ceejayoz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1902010/ceejayoz)'s input.

Comment: Half true. Apps can register to handle specific URL schemes, so Skype can be opened with a link to `skype:username?call`, for example.

Comment: @ceejayoz - On both iOS and Android or just Android?

Comment: Android has intents, so I believe you could attach to `tel:` links there.

Comment: Wow, I forgot all about it adding the browser extension. Answer to your Edit: Yes. I was hoping there was a universal way to make it happen.
Thanks to both of you for your input!